# Reporting Services: Use procedure as dataSet?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting

I'm starting with Reporting Services. I have SQL 2008 R2 Standard running. Reporting Services is up & running on the same server.

I created a stored procedure which takes one `int` as a parameter. In SQL Server, I have no problem running this as user "A".

I created a shared connection to SQL (with the sql user A), and I'm creating an embedded dataset. When I click on the "Stored procedure" radio button, I must fill in some information. I set the windows user which is authorized to connect to Reporting Services.

After this, I have a list of stored procedures, but not the one I created:[image: stored procedure list]

But I've set all the permissions for user A:
[image: TestProcedureSubjectUsage]

What am I missing?

I created my stored procedure before I created my project.

Comment: What happens if you choose the option "text" for "query Type" and enter `EXEC dbo.TestProcedureSubjectUsage` on the query?

Comment: In fact, I tried to put directly myself all information(procedure name, parameters, returns values), and it works. So the question is now: Why is the stored procedure not listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended by specifying myself procedure name and it works, it just can't display them in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue. Check the credentials you're using in the DataSource (not the DataSet) - it will need to be "UserA" or you'll need to assign permissions to the DataSource login.

Comment: The Data source use a shared connection. The user in this shared connection is "UserA". And if I put myself all information, the Stored procedure is correctly called, just not listed.